# In PostgreSQL, how to query for a computed results by the grouping of a field?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, count

In my PostgreSQL database I have an invitations table like so:

**Invitations Table:**

```
id, created_at, source, completed_at
```

**Fields Details**

```
id: integer
created_at: timestamp
source: varchar
completed_at: timestamp
```

I'd like to query the Invitations table and group by unique sources. And then per source, include the total # of records and the total of those completed. Completed being where complated_at is NOT NULL.

**Desired Results:**

```
columns: source, total, total_completed

source_a | 100 | 50
source_b | 200 | 33
source_c | 301 | 3
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation like so:

```
select source,  count(*) total, count(completed_at) total_completed
from invitations
group by source
```

`count(*)` counts all records in the group, while `count(completed_at)` counts only records whose `completed_at` is not `null`.